# Почему не работает роутинг в react native router flux при авторизации?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flux, reactjs

Всем привет. Делаю авторизацию в react native. Использую модуль для роутинга react native router flux. Вот начальный компонент.

```
export default class authreactnative extends Component {

  state = {
      loggedIn:false,
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {

    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

        this.setState({
          loggedIn:!!user,
        });

    });

  }
  render() {

    const { loggedIn } = this.state;
    const rootSelector = () => loggedIn ? 'home' : 'login';

    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root" tabs={true} selector={rootSelector}>
          <Scene key="login" >
            <Scene key="authuser" initial={true} component={Auth} title="auth"/>
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="home">
            <Scene key="appuser" initial={true} component={App} title="app"/>
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );

  }
}
```

Всегда срабатывает сцена login, хоть я вручную менял состояние, всегда открывает login. После успешной авторизации, ошибок нет, но не кидает на нужную мне сцену home. Консоль после авторизации пишет

```
Key authuser is already defined!
Key login is already defined!
Key appuser is already defined!
Key home is already defined!
Key root is already defined!
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Для перехода между сценами нужно использовать Actions. [Пример](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md)

```
export default class authreactnative extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
       Actions.home.appuser();// если есть вложеность Scene нужно писать полный путь Actions.Scene1.Scene2....()        
      }else{
     Actions.login.authuser();
     }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root" tabs={true}>
          <Scene key="login" >
            <Scene key="authuser" initial={true} component={Auth} title="auth"/>
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="home">
            <Scene key="appuser" component={App} title="app"/>
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );

  }
}
```